# How to make Satchmo work in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, e-commerce, satchmo

I understand that there are big differences in data-store, but surely since django is bundled and it abstracts data-store away from Satchmo, something can be done?

Truth is that I am not a Python guy, been mostly Java/PHP thus far, but I am willing to learn.

Plus, if this is not possible today, lets band together and form a new Open Source project to "extend" satchmo or perhaps branch it, for compatibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible if:

- Someone writes a generic ORM to Bigtable mapper. Most probably, [Appengine Patch Guys](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/app-engine-patch.html)
- Someone rewrites the views and models of Satchmo to remove existing ORM queries and use the minimal functionality of the ORM provided by the patch project, should be either you or the Satchmo guys.
- Someone hacks around a lot using the [django helper project](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/appengine_helper_for_django.html), can only be helper project guys.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. There are alot of dependencies in Satchmo that you aren't allowed to install on AppEngine.

See this thread as well: http://groups.google.com/group/satchmo-users/browse_thread/thread/509265ccd5f5fc1e?pli=1

Comment: Yea, I've seen that one... and why the negativity? 
I have sites running on osCommerce, but it's very outdated. There seems to be a vacuum of good e-commerce platforms nowadays...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is impossible - this will just require lots of effort - if there will be somebody wishing to do so - why not? But it might be easier (cheaper) to get Django friendly hosting instead of spending hours on hacking the code.