# eCommerce on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, e-commerce

I'm looking for an eCommerce platform that could be installed on Google App Engine.

Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[EngineCarts](http://www.enginecarts.com/static/engine_cart.html) is one such choice, but costs money AFAICT.

You could probably port over a existing python django app such as [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) fairly easily.

Comment: Satchmo can't run on GAE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600225/how-to-make-satchmo-work-in-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

Satchmo ,it sounds great, e-Commerce on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that Satchmo can be deployed to Google App. Eng. "easily" due to many dependent libs.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look on Google App Engine reported [issues or feature request](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). Its there.

Answer (score 0):

Freeblisket works with Google's App Engine, and it is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Viur has also a Shop modul including:

- shoppingcart
- workflow for paing
- adminworkflow for sending pakackes labeling payed status
- payingmethods like: paypal, google wallet, sofortüberweisung...

You also may structure your Productdatabase in:

- Folders
- Trees
- Lists and categories

it's open Source and you can download it at:

http://www.viur.is